# CORS + обращениe к API другого домена

Tags: javascript, api, cors

Балуюсь javascript в свободное время.
Захотелось вдруг создать себе для личного пользования страницу, которая будет выводить баланс моей банковской карточки.
Для этого, разумеется, я взялся использовать API, предоставленное банком.

До того времени я уже имел дело с запросами на удаленный сервер из видеоуроков. Например, я получал погоду с openweathermap API, или просто делал тестовые POST запросы на известный фейковый сервер jsonplaceholder. Всегда все работало. Тема запросов куда-либо меня нисколько не волновала.)

Но отправляя свой несчастный GET запрос в банк я столкнулся с:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/balance' from origin 'http://test.now' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Ошибка политики CORS, согласно которой, как оказалось, нельзя делать запросы на другой ресурс.
Ошибку удалось обойти, я использовал расширение для Chrome, которое, как я понял, выступает вроде прокси и вставляет нужные заголовки ответа (Access-Control-Allow-Origin), получаемые от сервера...

Так или иначе, хотел бы уточнить.

1. Выходит, что на одни "другие" ресурсы типа openweathermap я могу делать запросы, не получая ошибок CORS, а на другие ресурсы типа моего банка, где также общедоступное API - я не могу. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что некоторые ресурсы, которые предоставляют API, изначально задают заголовки ответов, позволяющие обходить правила CORS, а другие ресурсы этого не делают?
2. Как я еще понял, запросы вне браузера, то есть написанные на серверных языках - не будут проходить проверку CORS. Значит ли это, что для работы с API в большинстве случаев javascript - неподходящий язык? Ведь в готовом продукте ни о каком прокси речи не может идти, верно?

Заранее спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Очевидно что API вашего банка предназначено для использования не из браузера, поэтому оно не ставит заголовков CORS и поэтому и не работает в браузере. Сам язык javascript подходящий (он же не только в браузере используется, но например в NodeJS на сервере), но многие api типа вашего банка просто нельзя использовать из браузера из соображений безопасности

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А то, что удалось обойти СORS с помощью расширения (прокси). В готовых же проектах такое не используют? Это, наверное, костыль для разработки и тестирования, верно? Просто любопытно.

Comment: Ну да, костыль конечно. Но не думаю что даже для разработки есть большой смысл использовать. Сторонние api которые не рассчитаны на браузер никто на сайте использовать не будет. Значит будут делать свой собственный бекэнд, а он сам может отдавать любые заголовки какие захочет и если CORS нужны, то его научат их отдавать в первую очередь

Comment: И если какое то стороннее api не рассчитано на браузер, значит оно предполагает что вы его будете вызывать со стороны своего бакэнд сервера и видимо еще его данные где то у себя хранить, что бы каждого пользователя своего сайта не гонять к ним

Comment: Спасибо, Майк.)